# How to generate database tables programatically from annotated classes in Hibernate 5.2

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am developing a java web application with Hibernate for database connectivity, before this application I was using Hibernate 4.3.x and uses the following code for automatic creation of database tables

```
public class TableCreator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(AdminMaster.class);
        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(CorporateMaster.class);
        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Customer.class);
        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(LoginMaster.class);
        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Notifications.class);

        cfg.configure();
        SchemaExport se = new SchemaExport(cfg);
        se.create(true, true);
        System.out.println("Table Created!!!");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Now when I try to use the same code with Hibernate 5.2 following lines are shown in red in Netbeans

```
SchemaExport se = new SchemaExport(cfg);
se.create(true, true);
```

and the error shown is :

```
Schemaexport Class in Schemaexport cannot be applied to given types;
required : no arguments
found :configuration
```

I totally don't know what to do now, please help me guys..

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178041/where-did-configuration-generateschemacreationscript-go-in-hibernate-5 ,this link should help you.

Comment: Please read my question carefully , I am not saying that I have run the code, I am just saying that the lines are shown in red in Netbeans indicating some error , when I point my mouse on the exclamation mark in the begin of those lines , I see those errors..

Comment: @DeepakPandey can you Show the Import Statements?

Comment: import com.houseonholiday.entities.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html), the api has changed.

The constructor with Argument `configuration` does not exists anymore.

Comment: So what code should I use?