# How to read JPA entity file which as @Table & @Column annotation fields

Tags: jpa

I want to read JPA entity file through java reflection and find @Table and @Column annotation values and write it into excel file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is too vague : please see [ask]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to discover fully qualified table column from Hibernate MetadataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843457/how-to-discover-fully-qualified-table-column-from-hibernate-metadatasources)