# Replacing SchemaExport(Configuration) in Hibernate 5

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-5.x

While migrating from Hibernate 4 to 5 I came across the [deprecation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html#SchemaExport-org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration-) and eventual removal of the `SchemaExport(Configuration)` constructor. What is a good alternative in Hibernate 5?

### Use case

During testing we create a `SchemaExport` instance with a configuration that had some properties set and defines mapping resources:

```
// somewhere else `Properties` are filled and passed as a parameter
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
// more properties ...

Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setProperties(testProperties);
// parameter `String... mappingResources`
for (final String mapping : mappingResources) {
    configuration.addResource(mapping);
}

// this doesn't compile
SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport(configuration);
```

The last line does not compile on Hibernate 5 because the constructor was removed.

### Options

The deprecation recommends to use the `SchemaExport(MetadataImplementor)` constructor, but I struggle to find a good way to create a `MetadataImplementor` instance. I found a few options, but they all look fishy to me.

The only concrete implementations in Hibernate that I could find are `MetadataImpl` and `InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl`, but both are in `org.hibernate.boot.internal`, so I assume I'm not supposed to use them. Also, `MetadataImpl` has a massive constructor in which I need to provide every little detail and `InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl` needs a `MetadataBuildingOptions`, which has the same problems as `MetadataImplementor` (implementation is internal and hard to construct).

Alternatively, it looks like `MetadataBuilderImpl` might be a handy way to construct a `MetadataImplementor`, but it's also internal.

Either way, I couldn't find out how to set `Properties` (or their entries) on a `MetadataImplementor` (or `MetadataBuilderImpl` for that matter).

### Question

Is a `MetadataImplementor` really required to create a `SchemaExport`? If so, how do I get one from a supported API and how do I set `Properties`?

Eventually we want to execute a script with `execute`, but the signature changed here as well. I see it now takes a `ServiceRegistry`, so maybe that would be a way out?

## EDIT

Argh, I just saw that in 5.2 (which I want to use) `SchemaExport` does not even take a `MetadataImplementor` any longer - only the parameterless constructor remains. What now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where did Configuration.generateSchemaCreationScript() go in Hibernate 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178041/where-did-configuration-generateschemacreationscript-go-in-hibernate-5)

Answer (score 5):

In Hibernate, we have this base test class:

```
public class BaseNonConfigCoreFunctionalTestCase extends BaseUnitTestCase {
    public static final String VALIDATE_DATA_CLEANUP = "hibernate.test.validateDataCleanup";

    private StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
    private MetadataImplementor metadata;
    private SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory;

    private Session session;

    protected Dialect getDialect() {
        if ( serviceRegistry != null ) {
            return serviceRegistry.getService( JdbcEnvironment.class ).getDialect();
        }
        else {
            return BaseCoreFunctionalTestCase.getDialect();
        }
    }

    protected StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry() {
        return serviceRegistry;
    }

    protected MetadataImplementor metadata() {
        return metadata;
    }

    protected SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    protected Session openSession() throws HibernateException {
        session = sessionFactory().openSession();
        return session;
    }

    protected Session openSession(Interceptor interceptor) throws HibernateException {
        session = sessionFactory().withOptions().interceptor( interceptor ).openSession();
        return session;
    }

    protected Session getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    protected void rebuildSessionFactory() {
        releaseResources();
        buildResources();
    }

    protected void cleanupCache() {
        if ( sessionFactory != null ) {
            sessionFactory.getCache().evictAllRegions();
        }
    }

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // JUNIT hooks

    @BeforeClassOnce
    @SuppressWarnings( {"UnusedDeclaration"})
    protected void startUp() {
        buildResources();
    }

    protected void buildResources() {
        final StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = constructStandardServiceRegistryBuilder();

        serviceRegistry = ssrb.build();
        afterStandardServiceRegistryBuilt( serviceRegistry );

        final MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources( serviceRegistry );
        applyMetadataSources( metadataSources );
        afterMetadataSourcesApplied( metadataSources );

        final MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder = metadataSources.getMetadataBuilder();
        initialize( metadataBuilder );
        configureMetadataBuilder( metadataBuilder );

        metadata = (MetadataImplementor) metadataBuilder.build();
        applyCacheSettings( metadata );
        afterMetadataBuilt( metadata );

        final SessionFactoryBuilder sfb = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder();
        initialize( sfb, metadata );
        configureSessionFactoryBuilder( sfb );

        sessionFactory = (SessionFactoryImplementor) sfb.build();
        afterSessionFactoryBuilt( sessionFactory );
    }

    protected final StandardServiceRegistryBuilder constructStandardServiceRegistryBuilder() {
        final BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder bsrb = new BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder();
        bsrb.applyClassLoader( getClass().getClassLoader() );
        // by default we do not share the BootstrapServiceRegistry nor the StandardServiceRegistry,
        // so we want the BootstrapServiceRegistry to be automatically closed when the
        // StandardServiceRegistry is closed.
        bsrb.enableAutoClose();
        configureBootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder( bsrb );

        final BootstrapServiceRegistry bsr = bsrb.build();
        afterBootstrapServiceRegistryBuilt( bsr );

        final Map settings = new HashMap();
        addSettings( settings );

        final StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder( bsr );
        initialize( ssrb );
        ssrb.applySettings( settings );
        configureStandardServiceRegistryBuilder( ssrb );
        return ssrb;
    }

    protected void addSettings(Map settings) {
    }

    /**
     * Apply any desired config to the BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder to be incorporated
     * into the built BootstrapServiceRegistry
     *
     * @param bsrb The BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({"SpellCheckingInspection", "UnusedParameters"})
    protected void configureBootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder bsrb) {
    }

    /**
     * Hook to allow tests to use the BootstrapServiceRegistry if they wish
     *
     * @param bsr The BootstrapServiceRegistry
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedParameters")
    protected void afterBootstrapServiceRegistryBuilt(BootstrapServiceRegistry bsr) {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")
    private void initialize(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb) {
        final Dialect dialect = BaseCoreFunctionalTestCase.getDialect();

        ssrb.applySetting( AvailableSettings.CACHE_REGION_FACTORY, CachingRegionFactory.class.getName() );
        ssrb.applySetting( AvailableSettings.USE_NEW_ID_GENERATOR_MAPPINGS, "true" );
        if ( createSchema() ) {
            ssrb.applySetting( AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create-drop" );
            final String secondSchemaName = createSecondSchema();
            if ( StringHelper.isNotEmpty( secondSchemaName ) ) {
                if ( !H2Dialect.class.isInstance( dialect ) ) {
                    // while it may be true that only H2 supports creation of a second schema via
                    // URL (no idea whether that is accurate), every db should support creation of schemas
                    // via DDL which SchemaExport can create for us.  See how this is used and
                    // whether that usage could not just leverage that capability
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "Only H2 dialect supports creation of second schema." );
                }
                Helper.createH2Schema( secondSchemaName, ssrb.getSettings() );
            }
        }
        ssrb.applySetting( AvailableSettings.DIALECT, dialect.getClass().getName() );
    }

    protected boolean createSchema() {
        return true;
    }

    protected String createSecondSchema() {
        // poorly named, yes, but to keep migration easy for existing BaseCoreFunctionalTestCase
        // impls I kept the same name from there
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Apply any desired config to the StandardServiceRegistryBuilder to be incorporated
     * into the built StandardServiceRegistry
     *
     * @param ssrb The StandardServiceRegistryBuilder
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({"SpellCheckingInspection", "UnusedParameters"})
    protected void configureStandardServiceRegistryBuilder(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb) {
    }

    /**
     * Hook to allow tests to use the StandardServiceRegistry if they wish
     *
     * @param ssr The StandardServiceRegistry
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedParameters")
    protected void afterStandardServiceRegistryBuilt(StandardServiceRegistry ssr) {
    }

    protected void applyMetadataSources(MetadataSources metadataSources) {
        for ( String mapping : getMappings() ) {
            metadataSources.addResource( getBaseForMappings() + mapping );
        }

        for ( Class annotatedClass : getAnnotatedClasses() ) {
            metadataSources.addAnnotatedClass( annotatedClass );
        }

        for ( String annotatedPackage : getAnnotatedPackages() ) {
            metadataSources.addPackage( annotatedPackage );
        }

        for ( String ormXmlFile : getXmlFiles() ) {
            metadataSources.addInputStream( Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( ormXmlFile ) );
        }
    }

    protected static final String[] NO_MAPPINGS = new String[0];

    protected String[] getMappings() {
        return NO_MAPPINGS;
    }

    protected String getBaseForMappings() {
        return "org/hibernate/test/";
    }

    protected static final Class[] NO_CLASSES = new Class[0];

    protected Class[] getAnnotatedClasses() {
        return NO_CLASSES;
    }

    protected String[] getAnnotatedPackages() {
        return NO_MAPPINGS;
    }

    protected String[] getXmlFiles() {
        return NO_MAPPINGS;
    }

    protected void afterMetadataSourcesApplied(MetadataSources metadataSources) {
    }

    protected void initialize(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.enableNewIdentifierGeneratorSupport( true );
        metadataBuilder.applyImplicitNamingStrategy( ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl.INSTANCE );
    }

    protected void configureMetadataBuilder(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
    }

    protected boolean overrideCacheStrategy() {
        return true;
    }

    protected String getCacheConcurrencyStrategy() {
        return null;
    }

    protected final void applyCacheSettings(Metadata metadata) {
        if ( !overrideCacheStrategy() ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( getCacheConcurrencyStrategy() == null ) {
            return;
        }

        for ( PersistentClass entityBinding : metadata.getEntityBindings() ) {
            if ( entityBinding.isInherited() ) {
                continue;
            }

            boolean hasLob = false;

            final Iterator props = entityBinding.getPropertyClosureIterator();
            while ( props.hasNext() ) {
                final Property prop = (Property) props.next();
                if ( prop.getValue().isSimpleValue() ) {
                    if ( isLob( ( (SimpleValue) prop.getValue() ).getTypeName() ) ) {
                        hasLob = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ( !hasLob ) {
                ( ( RootClass) entityBinding ).setCacheConcurrencyStrategy( getCacheConcurrencyStrategy() );
            }
        }

        for ( Collection collectionBinding : metadata.getCollectionBindings() ) {
            boolean isLob = false;

            if ( collectionBinding.getElement().isSimpleValue() ) {
                isLob = isLob( ( (SimpleValue) collectionBinding.getElement() ).getTypeName() );
            }

            if ( !isLob ) {
                collectionBinding.setCacheConcurrencyStrategy( getCacheConcurrencyStrategy() );
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isLob(String typeName) {
        return "blob".equals( typeName )
                || "clob".equals( typeName )
                || "nclob".equals( typeName )
                || Blob.class.getName().equals( typeName )
                || Clob.class.getName().equals( typeName )
                || NClob.class.getName().equals( typeName )
                || BlobType.class.getName().equals( typeName )
                || ClobType.class.getName().equals( typeName )
                || NClobType.class.getName().equals( typeName );
    }

    protected void afterMetadataBuilt(Metadata metadata) {
    }

    private void initialize(SessionFactoryBuilder sfb, Metadata metadata) {
        // todo : this is where we need to apply cache settings to be like BaseCoreFunctionalTestCase
        //      it reads the class/collection mappings and creates corresponding
        //      CacheRegionDescription references.
        //
        //      Ultimately I want those to go on MetadataBuilder, and in fact MetadataBuilder
        //      already defines the needed method.  But for the [pattern used by the
        //      tests we need this as part of SessionFactoryBuilder
    }

    protected void configureSessionFactoryBuilder(SessionFactoryBuilder sfb) {
    }

    protected void afterSessionFactoryBuilt(SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory) {
    }

    @AfterClassOnce
    @SuppressWarnings( {"UnusedDeclaration"})
    protected void shutDown() {
        releaseResources();
    }

    protected void releaseResources() {
        if ( sessionFactory != null ) {
            try {
                sessionFactory.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println( "Unable to release SessionFactory : " + e.getMessage() );
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        sessionFactory = null;

        if ( serviceRegistry != null ) {
            try {
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( serviceRegistry );
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println( "Unable to release StandardServiceRegistry : " + e.getMessage() );
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        serviceRegistry=null;
    }

    @OnFailure
    @OnExpectedFailure
    @SuppressWarnings( {"UnusedDeclaration"})
    public void onFailure() {
        if ( rebuildSessionFactoryOnError() ) {
            rebuildSessionFactory();
        }
    }

    protected boolean rebuildSessionFactoryOnError() {
        return true;
    }

    @Before
    public final void beforeTest() throws Exception {
        prepareTest();
    }

    protected void prepareTest() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public final void afterTest() throws Exception {
        completeStrayTransaction();

        if ( isCleanupTestDataRequired() ) {
            cleanupTestData();
        }
        cleanupTest();

        cleanupSession();

        assertAllDataRemoved();
    }

    private void completeStrayTransaction() {
        if ( session == null ) {
            // nothing to do
            return;
        }

        if ( ( (SessionImplementor) session ).isClosed() ) {
            // nothing to do
            return;
        }

        if ( !session.isConnected() ) {
            // nothing to do
            return;
        }

        final TransactionCoordinator.TransactionDriver tdc =
                ( (SessionImplementor) session ).getTransactionCoordinator().getTransactionDriverControl();

        if ( tdc.getStatus().canRollback() ) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }

    protected boolean isCleanupTestDataRequired() {
        return false;
    }

    protected void cleanupTestData() throws Exception {
        doInHibernate(this::sessionFactory, s -> {
            s.createQuery("delete from java.lang.Object").executeUpdate();
        });
    }


    private void cleanupSession() {
        if ( session != null && ! ( (SessionImplementor) session ).isClosed() ) {
            session.close();
        }
        session = null;
    }

    public class RollbackWork implements Work {
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            connection.rollback();
        }
    }

    protected void cleanupTest() throws Exception {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings( {"UnnecessaryBoxing", "UnnecessaryUnboxing"})
    protected void assertAllDataRemoved() {
        if ( !createSchema() ) {
            return; // no tables were created...
        }
        if ( !Boolean.getBoolean( VALIDATE_DATA_CLEANUP ) ) {
            return;
        }

        Session tmpSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try {
            List list = tmpSession.createQuery( "select o from java.lang.Object o" ).list();

            Map<String,Integer> items = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
            if ( !list.isEmpty() ) {
                for ( Object element : list ) {
                    Integer l = items.get( tmpSession.getEntityName( element ) );
                    if ( l == null ) {
                        l = 0;
                    }
                    l = l + 1 ;
                    items.put( tmpSession.getEntityName( element ), l );
                    System.out.println( "Data left: " + element );
                }
                fail( "Data is left in the database: " + items.toString() );
            }
        }
        finally {
            try {
                tmpSession.close();
            }
            catch( Throwable t ) {
                // intentionally empty
            }
        }
    }



    public void inSession(Consumer<SessionImplementor> action) {
        log.trace( "#inSession(action)" );
        inSession( sessionFactory(), action );
    }

    public void inTransaction(Consumer<SessionImplementor> action) {
        log.trace( "#inTransaction(action)" );
        inTransaction( sessionFactory(), action );
    }

    public void inSession(SessionFactoryImplementor sfi, Consumer<SessionImplementor> action) {
        log.trace( "##inSession(SF,action)" );

        try (SessionImplementor session = (SessionImplementor) sfi.openSession()) {
            log.trace( "Session opened, calling action" );
            action.accept( session );
            log.trace( "called action" );
        }
        finally {
            log.trace( "Session close - auto-close lock" );
        }
    }

    public void inTransaction(SessionFactoryImplementor factory, Consumer<SessionImplementor> action) {
        log.trace( "#inTransaction(factory, action)");


        try (SessionImplementor session = (SessionImplementor) factory.openSession()) {
            log.trace( "Session opened, calling action" );
            inTransaction( session, action );
            log.trace( "called action" );
        }
        finally {
            log.trace( "Session close - auto-close lock" );
        }
    }

    public void inTransaction(SessionImplementor session, Consumer<SessionImplementor> action) {
        log.trace( "inTransaction(session,action)" );

        final Transaction txn = session.beginTransaction();
        log.trace( "Started transaction" );

        try {
            log.trace( "Calling action in txn" );
            action.accept( session );
            log.trace( "Called action - in txn" );

            log.trace( "Committing transaction" );
            txn.commit();
            log.trace( "Committed transaction" );
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.tracef(
                    "Error calling action: %s (%s) - rolling back",
                    e.getClass().getName(),
                    e.getMessage()
            );
            try {
                txn.rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception ignore) {
                log.trace( "Was unable to roll back transaction" );
                // really nothing else we can do here - the attempt to
                //      rollback already failed and there is nothing else
                //      to clean up.
            }

            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

which bootstrapts the `Metadata` and the `ServiceRegistry`.

So, we can call the `SchemaExport` like this:

```
new SchemaExport().create( EnumSet.of( TargetType.DATABASE ), metadata() );
```

Comment: I don't have a `ServiceRegistryBuilder` on my class path, only a `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder`. And it looks like the cast to `MetadataImplementor` is unnecessary in 5.2 because `SchemaExport` accepts `Metadata`.

Comment: You're right. I updated the entire class we are using.

Answer (score 5):

Distilling from other answers, I had to do the followings:

```
        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySetting("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create")
            .applySetting("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect")
            .applySetting("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "true")
            .build();
    MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry);
    managedClassNames.forEach(sources::addAnnotatedClass);
    MetadataImplementor metadata = (MetadataImplementor) sources
            .getMetadataBuilder()
            .build();

    SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport(metadata);
```

Hopefully that help

Comment: You didn't indicate how you populated managedClassNames? It just shows up in your code snippet.

Answer (score 4):

I like the diluted answer already posted. But here's a bit more detail that includes a few of the new built in Hibernate enums that allow you to create database tables with the `SchemaExport` class more programatically without a reliance on property file type settings like `hbm2ddl`.

### Use a `HashMap` for properties

Normally I like to include all the database settings in `Properties` type of object like a [`Hashtable or HashMap`](https://www.theserverside.com/video/HashMap-vs-Hashtable-Which-map-should-you-choose?_ga=2.145163773.87429035.1592921282-1563313008.1591538535). Then the `HashMap` is passed to the `ServiceRegistry`.

```
Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<>();
settings.put("connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
settings.put("dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
settings.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernate_examples");
settings.put("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
settings.put("hibernate.connection.password", "password");
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(settings).build();
```

### Add JPA entities to the `MetadataSources`

Then add all your JPA annotated classes to the `MetadataSources` object:

```
MetadataSources metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
metadata.addAnnotatedClass(Player.class);
```

### Use `Action` and `TargetType` Enums

After all that's done, it's time to create the `SchemaExport` class and call it's execute method. In doing so, you can use the `TargetType.DATABASE` enum and the `Action.BOTH` enum instead of putting `hbm2ddl` into the settings such as:

```
applySetting("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create")
```

Here's how it looks:

```
EnumSet<TargetType> enumSet = EnumSet.of(TargetType.DATABASE);
SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport();
schemaExport.execute(enumSet, Action.BOTH, metadata.buildMetadata());
```

And sorry if this gets long, but here's the whole version 5 Hibernate [`SchemaExport`](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/A-version-5-Hibernate-SchemaExport-example-with-the-ServiceRegistry-and-Metadata) code together in one go:

```
Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<>();
settings.put("connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
settings.put("dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
settings.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/jpa");
settings.put("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
settings.put("hibernate.connection.password", "password");
settings.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
settings.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");

ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(settings).build();

MetadataSources metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
//metadata.addAnnotatedClass(Player.class);

EnumSet<TargetType> enumSet = EnumSet.of(TargetType.DATABASE);
SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport();
schemaExport.execute(enumSet, Action.BOTH, metadata.buildMetadata());
```

The source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/cameronmcnz/hibernate-made-easy).

Comment: This also works for upgrading hibernate 3 to 6. You can also add xml mappings doing `serviceRegistry.configure(configFile)`.