# After migrating from 4.3 to 5.1 hibernate, SchemaExport is throwing exception

Tags: java, hibernate, migration, schemaexport

I migrate my hibernate from 4.3 to 5.1 and I have an exception with Schema Export. Hibernate migration guide mention about this but did not provide the solution.

I tried to use the metadata source and it dint help me.Below are the line which cause this issue that is in my HibernateUtils.

```
   public static List createDBSchema() {

    Configuration cfg = getConfiguration();
    SchemaExport dbSchema = new SchemaExport(cfg);
    dbSchema.create(false, true);

    return dbSchema.getExceptions();
}
```

Following is the error message after an mvn install in cmd.

```
HibernateUtils.java:[587,41] constructor SchemaExport in class org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR]   required: no arguments
[ERROR]   found: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
[ERROR]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
[ERROR] /C:/Development/Neon-Workspace/invitely_app/src/main/java/wadetech/DB/base/HibernateUtils.java:[588,33] incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to java.util.EnumSet<org.hibernate.tool.schema.TargetType>
```

Comment: How to reach people to get a help for this. Its very urgent for me.Thax

Comment: Seems like this was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432115/replacing-schemaexportconfiguration-in-hibernate-5

Comment: That one have answers for 5.2 and 5.0 and 4 and unfortunately not for 5.1. Thank you for responding though.

Comment: The API should be close enough between 5.2 5.1 and 5.0