# How to upgrade hbm2ddl schema creation with mappings at runtime?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm updating a Hibernate 3 project to Hibernate 6. At some point of the code, a schema with certain mappings is created using:

```java
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate;

public class SchemaGenerator {
    private void create() {
        SchemaUpdate schemaUpdate = new SchemaUpdate(getConfig());
        schemaUpdate.execute(false, true);
    }

    private Configuration getConfig() {
        if (cfg == null) {
            cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", driverClassName);
            cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", url);
            cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username);
            cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
            cfg.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
            cfg.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", Integer.toString(CommonConstants.JDBC_BATCH_SIZE));
            cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider");
            cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "true");
            cfg.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", username);
            cfg.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
            cfg.configure(configFile);
        }
        return cfg;
    }
}
```

My XML configuration file looks like:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="org.application.hibernate.Table"/>
    <session-factory>
<hibernate-configuration>
```

The problem is that the SchemaUpdate constructor no longer accepts any parameters, and I can't find how to pass the XML configuration to that object as well. You can see on [Hibernate 3 hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaUpdate.html) how this was valid.

I've been able to see on the [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl) that automatic schema generation is still supported, but the [examples](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/quickstart/html_single/#tutorial-native) are not really explaining what I'm looking for.

Comment: I think you need to read the "Bootstrap" chapter before the chapter you linked.

Comment: I've read thoroughly the chapter you mention @MarkRotteveel , and I see that the application is correctly bootstrapped. I think I forgot to mention the schema creation needs to happen at runtime at any requested time.

Comment: See [Legacy Bootstrap](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#appendix-legacy-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Map to build the `Metadata` object, which can then be passed to `SchemaExport` execute method:

```
public void createSchema() {
        Map<String, Object> settings = new HashMap<>();
        settings.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", driverClassName);
        settings.put("hibernate.connection.url", url);
        settings.put("hibernate.connection.username", username);
        settings.put("hibernate.connection.password", password);
        settings.put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
        settings.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", Integer.toString(CommonConstants.JDBC_BATCH_SIZE));
        settings.put("hibernate.connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider");
        settings.put("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "true");
        settings.put("hibernate.default_schema", username);
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(settings)
                .configure(configFile)  // We could also add annotated classes at metadata object (?)
                .build();
        MetadataSources metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
        EnumSet<TargetType> enumSet = EnumSet.of(TargetType.DATABASE);
        SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport();
        schemaExport.execute(enumSet, SchemaExport.Action.CREATE, metadata.buildMetadata());
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62610312/9159340)