# Standalone schema export Hibernate Validator integration

Tags: hibernate, ddl, schemaexport

as explained here:

http://devmint.blogspot.com/2013/02/hibernate-schema-export-with-hibernate.html

the validator specific annotations are not recognized by SchemaExport any longer.

How can method "injectBeanValidationConstraintToDdlTranslator" be translated to Hibernate 5.2 ?

The configuration file no longer exists as stated here:

[Where did Configuration.generateSchemaCreationScript() go in Hibernate 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178041/where-did-configuration-generateschemacreationscript-go-in-hibernate-5)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following way to achive the evaluation of the validator properties during a schema export for Hibernate 5.1.

Add a new Class **CustomMetadataContributor**:

```
package de.test;

import org.hibernate.MappingException;
import org.hibernate.boot.internal.ClassLoaderAccessImpl;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService;
import org.hibernate.boot.spi.ClassLoaderAccess;
import org.hibernate.boot.spi.InFlightMetadataCollector;
import org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataContributor;
import org.hibernate.cfg.SecondPass;
import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;
import org.hibernate.engine.config.spi.ConfigurationService;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.JdbcServices;
import org.jboss.jandex.IndexView;

import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;

public class CustomMetadataContributor implements MetadataContributor {

    public void contribute(InFlightMetadataCollector metadataCollector, IndexView jandexIndex){
        metadataCollector.addSecondPass(new SecondPass() {
            @Override
            public void doSecondPass(final Map persistentClasses) throws MappingException {
                try {
                    Method applyDDL = Class.forName("org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator") //
                            .getMethod("applyRelationalConstraints", ValidatorFactory.class, Collection.class, Map.class, Dialect.class, ClassLoaderAccess.class);
                    applyDDL.setAccessible(true);
                    StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = metadataCollector.getMetadataBuildingOptions().getServiceRegistry();
                    applyDDL.invoke(null, Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory() ,metadataCollector.getEntityBindings(), serviceRegistry.getService( ConfigurationService.class ).getSettings(), serviceRegistry.getService( JdbcServices.class ).getDialect(),new ClassLoaderAccessImpl(serviceRegistry.getService( ClassLoaderService.class )));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Moreover you need to add a textfile (without a file extension) in path

**META-INF/services/org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataContributor**

containing

```
de.test.CustomMetadataContributor
```

whereas *de.test* needs to be replaced with your package name.