# Facing problem in upgrading hibernate from 4.x to 5.x

Tags: hibernate

Configutration.generateSchemaCreationScript() is removed from hibernate 5.x. My existing code snippets as below,

```
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.addInputStream(hbmFileInputStream);
    cfg.addInputStream(hbmStandTabFileInputStream);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(hibPropertiesStream);
    cfg.setProperties(props);
    final Dialect dialect = Dialect.getDialect(cfg.getProperties());
    String[] createSQL = cfg.generateSchemaCreationScript(dialect);
```

Please share the code snippets if someone is already upgraded above type of code.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where did Configuration.generateSchemaCreationScript() go in Hibernate 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178041/where-did-configuration-generateschemacreationscript-go-in-hibernate-5)

Comment: I have already gone through this post. I am looking a way to return string array